# Was there a forest in Armenia (around the city of Ani) between 961 and 1045?

Tags: cities, climate, armenia, forestry

Recently I discovered the existence of the ancient city of Ani (Armenia) which was "one of the world's largest cities, with a possible population of circa 100,000." between 961 and 1045. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ani), or this [article from The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2014/01/the-ancient-ghost-city-of-ani/100668/)

Pictures of the ruins are stunning and show an advanced civilization, equivalent to what can be found in Europe. The city seems to be lost in an empty steppe, without resources and forest.

Was the vegetation around the city similar to what we see nowadays (a steppe without trees)? In particular, was there a forest at that time, now gone due to timber production?

Comment: What is your actual question? (Please edit answer into the question body rather than responding in a comment - questions must stand independent of their comments.)

Comment: What are your reasons for suspecting it might have been forested specifically? That information might help people answer the question.

Comment: It's because of the architecture looks similar to western Europe, where forests have been extensively used for resources (building material, energy and food), but there natural resources seem to be scarce... for instance, I imagine large trees are needed for the scaffolding ?

Comment: Wikipedia article on [Bagratid Armenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagratid_Armenia) describes trade networks and mentions that "From Ani, Armenia exported... timber," among many other products. It's not clear to me where that timber originated, but the footnote points to Hewsen's [*Historical Atlas*, p. 12](https://archive.org/details/hewsen-maps-09-11th/page/n1/mode/2up?q=timber).

Comment: Well, your question seems more appropirate for geology or enviornmental scientists rather than historians. I’m a bit confused by your claim that architecture looks like Western Europe. Can you add some pictures to your question to show what architecture you are referring to exactly here?

Comment: Ah. Well there appear to be a [decent amount of forests even *today*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk028KHQe9ct5Pe2y-qfBkT7Q8OG_4Q:1594996197809&q=armenia+forest&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=40580656,44599365,66100&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwjOjKfuv9TqAhUHM6wKHZDEA-gQtgN6BAgLEAQ&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:[[40.8213776556524,45.25809086309825],[39.58799766068484,42.9317358826295],null,[40.20749292117561,44.09491337286388],9]) nearsh over in modern Armenia. I'd wager some of those were forest in ancient times as well.

Comment: This does sound as if it would be more appropriate as "Was the landscape around the city of Ani similar..." but nevertheless is an interesting query!

Comment: @gagik: I am not familiar with the area and time. Generally, to find a reliable source one could search for palynological data from the time. This is done in the course of archeological excavations, or when building a continuous dendrochronological time scale. If such things exist for the area, it should be possible to find out about the state of forests and species of trees.